# Combining two Stream<List<Model>> streams into one

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

I have two functions that both return a Stream of a objects from a Firebase database:

```
  Stream<List<Model>> getAllCondition1() {
      final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('model')
          .withConverter<Model>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
          toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson());
      return reference.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
        final list = snapshot.docs.map((document) {
          return document.data();
        }).toList();
        return list;
      });
  }
```

I would now like to combine two similar functions that filter for different conditions and thereby create a "or" query:

```
  Stream<List<Model>> getMerged() {
    final streamOpen = getAllCondition1();
    final streamClosed = getAllCondition2();
    return ConcatStream([streamOpen, streamClosed]);
  }
```

If streamOpen is a List of [1,2] and streamClosed a List of [3,4,5] I would like to receive a list of [1,2,3,4,5]. With the ConcatStream function I receive [1,2].

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: check `rxDart` package and its `combineLatest` function

Comment: @pskink - I tried this as well. When I use `return CombineLatestStream.list([streamOpen, streamClosed])` I get an error that Stream<List<Model>> can't be assigned to the list type Stream<Model>. How would I merge the two lists in the combine function?

Comment: @Olf  I have same problem. Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most elegant solution but this seems to work:

```
    return CombineLatestStream.combine2(streamOpen, streamClosed, (List<Todo>s1,List<Todo>s2) { final s3 = s1; s3.addAll(s2); return s3;});
```